# iTunes mixes up Aperture and iPhoto

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos.app, aperture, library

I use iPhoto for my mobile (iPhone, iPad) pictures and I have a separate library in Aperture for the pictures I take with my DSLR.

Until now I was just transferring my mobile photos to iPhoto.

Now I want to sync my iPhoto library (at least some of my albums) to my iPhone. The problem is: in iTunes, in the photo tab, I have only one option in the "Sync photos from" dropdown, iPhoto, BUT when I select it, it's the Aperture library that shows up.

It seems to me that there was a time when I had both options, iPhoto and Aperture, in the dropdown. It must have come from an update…

Any ideas on how to sort thing up?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it.

You just have to create a new library (open iPhoto with the <kbd>alt</kbd> key pressed), quit iPhoto, and open it again with <kbd>alt</kbd> pressed and select the original library file. Open iTunes, et voilà!